# Test error correlation with label frequency

Tags: classification, svm

For a university project I wrote a SVM classifier and during the benchmark phase I'm getting some results I'd like to better understand from the theoretical side.

My original dataset contains a multi-labeled examples but I'm buiding a binary classifier so I pick a feature `A` and I replace all the labels with +1 if `A` is present or -1 if it isn't. For instance:

```
label1 label2 label3 label4 = feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4
label2 label4  = feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4
label3 label4  = feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4
```

If choose `label3` the dataset becomes:

```
 1 = feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4
-1  = feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4
 1  = feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4
```

If choose `label2` the dataset becomes:

```
 1 = feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4
 1  = feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4
-1  = feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4
```

Now, my original dataset contains 20k rows and:

1. If I choose a label which is in 9k rows I get a average test error of 13%
2. If I choose a label which is in 5k rows I get a average test error of 7%

I was wondering why this is happening. My guesses are:

- In the second case the separating hyperplane has a larger margin
- In this the first case the is overfitting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that test error rate alone does not give you the full story and may be deceiving. You did not describe the test set, so I am going to assume its distribution is identical to what you use for training (as is the case when you use a random split).

To illustrate why error rate alone is deceiving, we can use a dumb classifier that always yields `positive`. Lets test it on two different test sets, which is similar to what I believe you are doing:

- balanced test set ($50\%$ positives, $50\%$ negatives) $\rightarrow$ $50\%$ error rate
- unbalanced test set ($90\%$ positives, $10\%$ negatives) $\rightarrow$ $10\%$ error rate

Using a single measure to assess performance is a bad idea. You should look at error rate + NPV + PPV or error rate + sensitivity + specificity to obtain more insight into what is going on.

If you really want to evaluate performance with a single number, some more sensible summaries include area under the ROC or PR curves, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. BTW, the error I wrote above is the average I got performing k-fold validation (with k=10).